# i dont know how to take input in one textbox and show show output in other textbox

Tags: python, pyqt5

I don't know how to take input of user in one textbox and show output in other textbox.

I tried but it's not working.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os

def click(self):
    self.pushButton.click()
    print("hello")

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(664, 389)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/background/White-Marble-Background-product-Photography-backdrops-Newborn-Photo-props-baby-shower-PhotoCall-pictures-newborn-propsXt-6735.jpg_640x640.webp);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 621, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        inp_val = self.lineEdit.text()

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 290, 151, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rubik")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(240, 184, 160);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(click(self))


        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 621, 191))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit.setCursorWidth(2)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Rahul"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type Your Text Here....."))
        self.textEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your Output....."))
import test2_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I input in lineedit and show output in textedit?

Comment: Is textedit  compulsory ?

Comment: Also please post only relevant code. Your code is huge.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# ? import os

#def click(self):
#    self.pushButton.click()
#    print("hello")

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(664, 389)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/background/White-Marble-Background-product-Photography-backdrops-Newborn-Photo-props-baby-shower-PhotoCall-pictures-newborn-propsXt-6735.jpg_640x640.webp);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 621, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        inp_val = self.lineEdit.text()

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 290, 151, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rubik")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(240, 184, 160);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(click(self))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClick)


        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 621, 191))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit.setCursorWidth(2)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def onClick(self):
#        self.pushButton.click()
        print("hello")
        self.textEdit.append(self.lineEdit.text())                   # <---


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Rahul"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type Your Text Here....."))
        self.textEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your Output....."))

# ? import test2_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: its done but one thing remainig that i want to print the output in text edit box but its showing in pycharm output area i dont know what its called might a console of pycharm  code...>   def onClick(self):
        self.textEdit.append(os.system(self.lineEdit.text()))

Answer (score 0):

Use `setPlainText`:

```py
def click(self):
    inputtext = self.lineEdit.text()
    self.textEdit.setPlainText(inputtext)
```

Also you need to put function `click` inside class `Ui_MainWindow`, like this:

```py
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #your code
    def click(self):
        inputtext = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.textEdit.setPlainText(inputtext)
```

Also call function `click` like:

```py
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)
```